# If we're trying to attract attention to a specific event, how much should messaging focus on only the event?

Tags: user-engagement, physical-communities, social-network

My synagogue is holding a food festival in a couple months to raise money. For budget reasons, the planners want to do advertising exclusively on social media (as opposed to, say, newspapers or billboards).

Since we're a minority religion in the community, the goal of the event is to showcase various cultural, heritage, and culinary traditions as well as make a bit of money. There's some debate over the best way to target advertising, though.

Should social media posts...

- focus exclusively on foods/traditions that are going to available (for example, "We'll be serving delicious brisket, here's what brisket is!")
- focus on what makes us unique (even if it won't be at this event, for example "Here's some fun Yiddish you might want to use in the kitchen!")
- tie into whatever's going on that day or around town (for example, "Happy St. Patrick's Day, did you know corned beef was originally Jewish not Irish?")